# Unir cuatro tablas usando Join

Tags: mysql

En mi DB tengo un escenario con Cuatro tablas y hago esta consulta con base en ellas:

```
SELECT T1.`demo_eleccion_ideleccion` AS `Ideleccion`,
         T1.`idcandidatos` AS `Idcandidatos`,
         T1.`nombre` AS `Candidatos`,
         T1.`numero` AS `Numero_Tarjeton`,
         T1.`tarjeton` AS `tarjeton`
From demo_candidatos T1
Left Outer Join demo_registro T2 ON T1.idcandidatos = T2.candidato
Left Outer Join demo_voting T3 ON T2.codigo_votante = T3.codigo
where T2.codigo_votante is null
```

Tablas

[image: tabla demo_candidatos]

[image: tabla demo_eleccion]

[image: tabla demo_registro]

[image: tabla demo_voting]

Con base en el escenario, en la tabla demo_registro (codigo_votante) ya votó el código numero 111111; de los dos disponibles (111111 y 333333), el problema está en que sólo me está permitiendo realizar una votación en general, debería permitirme votar utilizando el código 333333, que aún esta disponible.

Gracias, por la ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Por [edítala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/135974/edit), tratando de explicar con más claridad qué es lo que quieres y poniendo un ejemplo de los resultados esperados. Gracias.

Comment: Básicamente no deberían ser cargados los registros de la tabla demo_candidatos cuando codigo_votante y el idcanditatos existe en la tabla demo_registro.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, el código está muy confuso. En primer lugar intenta editarla explicando el enunciado de lo que necesitas hacer y segundo, indica el diseño lógico de tu DB o al menos de las tablas implicadas.

Comment: Ok tenías razon,le he dado más claridad a mi consulta con datos de ejemplo!